# Adding node to a pgfplots-plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following plot in TikZ:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[domain=2:6,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  no markers,
  ymin=-0.5,ymax=1,
  axis lines=left,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty]
\addplot +[thick, black] {ln(4/x)};
\node [left]  at (3,0) {$F$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see, I have tried to add a node at the coordinate `(3,0)`, however, it isn't showing. What am I missing to make it appear?

Comment: put `\node [left]  at (3,0) {$F$};`
 after `end{axis}`

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have `compat=1.11` or higher, so the coordinates of the node are not that of the axis. Try `(axis cs:3,0)` instead of `(3,0)`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That worked. But I am only able to place the node inside the coordinate system - not outside. Basically, what I want is for it to say `F` instead of `3` at the point `x=3`, i.e., to change the axis marker/label at x=3

Comment: Oh, then you're going about it the wrong way, if I understood correctly. You want `xtick=3,xticklabels=$F$` instead of `xtick=empty`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Very nice, thanks! Feel free to add an answer I can accept

Comment: Half of the question is [tikz pgf - Nodes not appearing on TikZpicture - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592662/nodes-not-appearing-on-tikzpicture) but this one also has some clipping problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the node, is that coordinates for `\node`, `\draw` and similar drawing macros from TikZ are not, by default, in the coordinates of the `pgfplots` axis. That, and the fact that `pgfplots` clips away everything outside the axis limits. So your node ends up outside the axis limits, and is clipped.

To actually use axis coordinates for a `\node`, you can define the coordinate system to use explicitly with `axis cs:`:

```
\node at (axis cs:3,0) {..};
```

Alternatively `axis cs` can me made default, by adding

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
```

or some higher version number. Currently the latest version i 1.17, so `compat=1.17` is the highest valid version number. (It's probably a good idea to always specify the `compat` setting I think, for one thing even the lowest possible value (`1.3`) will improve the placement of the `ylabel`.)

However, based on the comments, what you're actually after is to add a custom ticklabel for x=3. The normal way to do that is to use `xtick=3` in the `axis` options to specify that you want a tick at x=3, and then use `xticklabels=$F$` to specify the text to use for the label.

More generally you can use comma separated lists in `{}` for both, e.g. `xtick={3,7}, xticklabels={foo,bar}`, or use the dots notation for ranges, e.g. `1,3,...,10` which gets you the odd numbers from 1 to 9.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % it's recommended to use an explicit version number
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[domain=2:6,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  no markers,
  ymin=-0.5,ymax=1,
  axis lines=left,xtick=3,xticklabels=$F$,ytick=\empty]
\addplot +[thick, black] {ln(4/x)};

% with the compat setting used above this adds the node at 3,0 in the axis
\node [left]  at (3,0) {$F$};

% while this would work regardless of the compat setting
\node [right]  at (axis cs:3,0) {$G$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also the OP is probably affected by clipping. If you add `clip mode = individual` the manually added `\draw` and `\node` command are not clipped in the axis range.

Comment: @Rmano Yes, I did mention clipping, but I didn't think about `clip mode`, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define coordinates inside the axis environment and plot them outside to avoid clipping.  The following assumes you want x=3 for `[domain=2:6]` but at the bottom edge of the plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[domain=2:6,
  samples=100,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  no markers,
  ymin=-0.5,ymax=1,
  axis lines=left,xtick=3,xticklabels=$F$,ytick=\empty]
\addplot +[thick, black] {ln(4/x)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:3,0);% y value unimportant
\coordinate (B) at (rel axis cs: 0,0);% lower left corner
\end{axis}
\node [left]  at (A|-B) {$F$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]