# Nodes not appearing on TikZpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

After I copied a TikZpicture over to another document, the nodes stopped appearing, and I got a "dimension too large" issue with the node at x=46200, furthest to the right. The xmax was 50000. I created a minimal working example (MWE) to try find the problem, but even in the MWE, the nodes now don't appear.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, pgfplots, %(makes compiling slower)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=60000, xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:17712] {0.292 + 0.616/(2+x/3542.4)};
%\addplot [domain=0:17712] {0.38*2 - 0.38/17712*x};
%\addplot [domain=17712:36000] {0.38*2 - 0.38/17712*x};
\node [anchor=west] at (2400, 0.74) {$k(Y_i) = 0.38\times 2 - \frac{0.38}{17712}\cdot Y_i$};
%\addplot [domain=7000:17712] {0.38*17712/x};
%\addplot [domain=17712:60000] {0.38*17712/x};
%\addplot [domain=0:17712] { 0.6 - 0.22/17712*x};
%\addplot [domain=0:60000] {0.38};
\node [anchor=west] at (900, 0.45) {$h(Y_i)$};
\node [anchor=west] at (2000, 0.595) {$f(Y_i)$};
\node [anchor=east] at (46200
, 0.228
) {$q(Y_i) = \frac {0.38\times 17712}{Y_i}$};
\node [anchor=south west] at (17712, 0.38) {$(17712, 0.38)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image: MWE output]

The graph that I had previously was

[image: Full graph (previously)]

with [this code](https://pastebin.com/JCbjvwzg).

Comment: Probably you missed a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` (or whatever >=1.11). Before that version the coordinates were not interpreted in the axis coordinate system by default. You should have a big warning in the log...

Comment: Yes, `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` worked!

Comment: Related question [tikz pgf - Make "axis cs" the default coordinate system in a PGFPlots plot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208488/make-axis-cs-the-default-coordinate-system-in-a-pgfplots-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```latex
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
```

to your preamble you have:

[image]

The reason is because at a certain version (I think 1.11), the default coordinates inside the `axis` environment changed from the raw Ti*k*Z ones to the user-defined ones. If you don't state you want the new state-of-things explicitly, `pgfplots` keep the old compatibility way.

Anyway, you should had this warning in your file:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode 
(unsuitable tick labels; missing features). 
Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into your preamble.
```